# Do we need Seeking Debugging Help anymore?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Due to the new wording of the close reasons, "Unclear" became this:

> Needs details or clarity
>   Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question.

To me, that covers stuff in the off-topic -> seeking debugging close reason:

> It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behaviour, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem

So do we actually need to keep this reason in the closure list?

---

I chucked the idea out in a chat room first and it was noted that this could lead to increased closures for good "How To.." questions. For that reason, I'd suggest another A/B test to see if the good "how to" questions are being closed when the seeking debugging reason goes or if it more or less stays the same (with the latter being ideal).

Comment: I disagree. I see no negative impact in keeping this close reason. Does it cause any harm to the website or community?

Comment: @Dharman No but feels like it holds no positive impact either, just feels like it would be more efficient to have one less click for more or less the same reason (in my eyes)

Comment: You are asking the company to implement an A/B testing and potentially a huge change just because one more click is too much for you?

Comment: The "seeking debugging help" reason should be preferred in cases of overlap because it is more directly applicable, more expressive, and gives more actionable advice.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think either of two new reasons is any more actionable... The old one for MRE had a link which made it better for my taste, but now both are just text...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes we do.

### Seeking debugging

This reason is used to let OP know that Stack Overflow is not a bunch of psychics who can debug the code code for you. We need to see the code, the actual result, the expect result and error messages if there are any. We can't guess what went wrong in your code if you have not shown any of it to us. e.g. [Hi i dont seem to be getting the get info on paypal intergration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59750640/1839439)

You could say these are the details, but I would argue that this is the core of the question. If the question is looking for debugging help we expect that you provide us a reproducible example aka [MCVE]

### Needs details or clarity

This close reason is used for questions which ask about tackling a specific programming problem, but are too vague to provide a meaningful answer. They can either be completely incomprehensible or just ambiguous. Maybe we need to know which technology you are using. Maybe we need to know what exact output you want to achieve. There could be many reasons why the question is unclear, but missing code/error message should not be one of them. e.g. [I want to ask about codingan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743908/i-want-to-ask-about-codingan)

There will always be an overlap between the close reasons. We do not need less closure reasons. I would even argue we need more. It is ok if two or more reason suit a particular question, we can then pick the one which is going to describe the issue better.

Comment: Good answer, @Dharman! I was *thinking* of editing 'psychics' to 'side-kicks' but, ultimately, refrained!

Comment: Oh, so I probably flagged for the wrong reason, sometimes. I usually flagged _missing code questions_ with **Needs details or clarity**.

Comment: @Cubo78 *Only debugging questions require code* (i.e. a [mcve]). Other question types don't *require* code (homework Qs require an attempt). For other types of questions, code often greatly helps to clarify and narrow the scope (i.e. they're often "Needs details or clarity (Unclear)" or "Needs more focus (Too broad)" without code), but code isn't *required*. Some of the best questions on Stack Overflow have no code (e.g. many "How to" questions). But, the question *must* be clear as to what the OP is asking/trying to accomplish and narrow enough in scope to be covered in an answer.

Comment: @Cubo78 before last change of text "missing MRE" close reason had actually more helpful information (MRE link in particular) so preferring that one was my choice. Now both are just text and there is no need to prefer one over another.